# REACT REDUX connect fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
var initialState = {
                value:0
                }


        //action creators
        function clickAdd() {
          return {
              type: CLICK_ADD
          }
        }

        function clickSub() {
          return {
              type: CLICK_SUB
          }
        }

        //reducre 
        function reducre(state, action) {
          if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
            return 0
          }
          var value;
          switch(action.type) {
              case 'CLICK_ADD': {
                  value = state + 1;
                  return value

              }
              case 'CLICK_SUB': {
                  value = state - 1;
                  return value

              }
              default :{
                  return state
              }
          }
        }

        var store = Redux.createStore(reducre,initialState)
        var ButtonGroup = React.createClass({


             clickAdd(event) {  
                    this.props.dispatch(clickAdd());  
                }  ,

          render() {

              const { value } = this.props;  


                return (
                  <ButtonToolbar style={{width: 17+ 'em'}} >
                  <Button  id="search"  }>{value}</Button>
                  <Button  onClick={this.clickAdd} }>ADD</Button>
                  </ButtonToolbar>
                );
              }
        });

        function select(state) {  
            return {  
                value: state.value
            }  
        }  

        connect(select)(ButtonGroup);


        ReactDOM.render(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <ButtonGroup/>
          </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('button_container')
        );
```

i am doing react with redux without ES6 or Webpack, 
i followed some example online but it shows 
what i want to do is clicking the button and increasing the number of click and show on the next button . this.props.dispatch is not a function and 
Uncaught ReferenceError: CLICK_ADD is not defined 
i dont know if my connection is right , anyone help? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Action creators, `CLICK_ADD` and `CLICK_SUB` are variables which isn't defined, either you define it like

```
var CLICK_ADD = 'CLICK_ADD';
var CLICK_SUB = 'CLICK_SUB';

function clickAdd() {
    return {
        type: CLICK_ADD
    }
}
function clickSub() {
    return {
        type: CLICK_SUB
    }
}
```

or use it as a String like

```
function clickAdd() {
    return {
        type: 'CLICK_ADD'
    }
}

function clickSub() {
    return {
        type: 'CLICK_SUB'
    }
}
```

Also you need to make use of `connected` button component

```
   const NewButtonGroup = connect(select)(ButtonGroup);


    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NewButtonGroup/>
      </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('button_container')
    );
```

Comment: it works thx a lot ,but for the above coding , am i connect redux wrongly?  coz it shows this.props.dispatch is not a function .thx

Comment: I think you have a syntax error on `onClick={this.clickAdd} }`,  and you are not using the connected ButtonGroup component

Answer (score 0):

In your actions you are referring to a constant and in your reducers you are referring to a string. It should work after you initialise your action types on the following way:

```
const CLICK_ADD = 'CLICK_ADD';
const CLICK_SUB = 'CLICK_SUB';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clickAdd() {
          return {
              type: CLICK_ADD
          }
        }
```

In this funciton you should use CLICK_ADD as string